# Get overflow from arithmetic operations

Tags: c, math, integer-overflow

When doing a math operation, how can I get the part that overflowed?

For example, assuming 32-bit ints:

```
unsigned int a = 0Xffffffff;
unsigned int b = 0xffffffff;
unsigned int c = a + b;
```

In this case, `c` is `0xfffffffe`, but the answer should be `0x1fffffffe`. How do I get the 1 that overflowed?

How can I do the same for multiplication? Can I multiply two large numbers together and only get the overflowed part?

How do bigint libraries manage this?

Comment: May be [relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)

Comment: How about bit shifting with 64 bit integers?

Comment: Since the sum of the two numbers is larger than the storage, there is nowhere to store the number, which is why there is an overflow. If you could just check somewhere for the overflow there would be no need for it to be an overflow at all. But, you can detect the overflow and do something else, `if(UINT_MAX - a < b) then handle_it()`

Comment: `unsigned long long int` is a standard C type that must have at least 64 bits, so, for your 32-bit example, the product can be computed as `(unsigned long long int) a * b`, after which the low and high 32 bits can be extracted by shifting and masking.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing.GerhardStein problem will come bach with unsigned long long. What type then?

Comment: Q: How do I get the 1 that overflowed?  A: Sadly, you can't.  WORKAROUNDS: a) perform arithmetic using a larger integer type (and check higher order bits), b) Write inline assembly to check the CPU's carry flag, etc..  See also: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/.  Most of the discussion is equally applicable to C.

Answer (score 3):

@Warning NOT PORTABLE@

1. Use https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Example:  https://godbolt.org/z/NcyNzR

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int res;

    if(__builtin_uadd_overflow(0Xffffffff, 0Xffffffff, &res))
    {
        printf("Overflowed\n");
    }
    printf("Result: 0x%x\n", res);
}
```

2. Use inline assembly to read the carry flag

Answer (score 2):

Assuming unsigned type operands, you can write:

```
bool cf = a+b<a;
```

or

```
bool cf = a>-1-b;
```

These work regardless of the existence of a larger type to work with.

Multiplication is harder; without a larger type, there is no way to access the upper half of the result. If you do have one you can use it. For example, if your operands are `uint32_t`,

```
uint32_t upper = ((uint64_t)a * b) >> 32;
uint32_t lower = a*b;
```

Otherwise, you're stuck dropping to a half-sized type and using long multiplication. For example, with `uint64_t a,b;`

```
uint32_t al = a, ah = a>>32;
uint32_t bl = b, bh = b>>32;
```

And then the upper part of the result is `ah*bh` plus the carry out of adding `al*bh`, `ah*bl`, and the upper bits of `al*bl`.

Bigint libraries can avoid the pain of this by just choosing a limb type that's at most half the width of the largest integer type.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the 1 that overflowed?

To do it afterwards in a portable way (not forgetting that `unsigned int` might only be 16 bits):

```
    uint32_t a = 0Xffffffff;
    uint32_t b = 0xffffffff;
    uint32_t c_low = a + b;
    uint32_t c_high;
    if(c_low >= a) {
        c_high = 0;
    } else {
        c_high = 1;
    }
```

To do it beforehand in a portable way (without branches):

```
    uint32_t a = 0Xffffffff;
    uint32_t b = 0xffffffff;
    uint32_t c_low;
    uint32_t c_high;

    c_high = (a&b) >> 31;
    c_low = (a ^ (c_high<<31)) + b;
```

> How can I do the same for multiplication?

Multiplication doesn't have a carry, it has an "upper half". Specifically; if you multiply an unsigned integer that has N bits with an unsigned integer that has M bits then the result will have N+M bits; and if both numbers had the same size then the result will be twice as big.

Sadly C doesn't support "result type is larger than source/s types", so you need to "pre-promote" the source types, like:

```
    uint32_t a = 0Xffffffff;
    uint32_t b = 0xffffffff;
    uint64_t temp = (uint64_t)a * (uint64_t)b;
    uint32_t c_low = temp;
    uint32_t c_high = temp >> 32;
```

Of course if the compiler doesn't support a larger type then you have to split it into smaller pieces, like:

```
    uint32_t a = 0Xffffffff;
    uint32_t b = 0xffffffff;

    uint32_t a_low = a & 0xFFFF;
    uint32_t a_high = a >> 16;
    uint32_t b_low = a & 0xFFFF;
    uint32_t b_high = b >> 16;

    uint32_t temp_0 = a_low * b_low;
    uint32_t temp_16a = a_high * b_low;
    uint32_t temp_16b = a_low * b_high;
    uint32_t temp_32 = a_high * b_high;

    uint32_t c_low = temp_0 + (temp16a << 16) + (temp16b << 16);
    uint32_t c_high = (temp16a >> 16) + (temp16b >> 16) + temp_32;
```

> How do bigint libraries manage this?

Mainly; they use inline assembly language because most CPUs support instructions to work on bigger integers efficiently and/or because you can access the carry flag directly. For example; for 80x86; the CPU has `adc`/`sbb`, `shld`/`shrd`, `mul` (with double width result)/`div` (with double width numerator); plus maybe extensions (`adcx` and `adox`).

In 32-bit 80x86 assembly language, the addition might look like:

```
    xor edx,0
    add eax,ebx      ;c_low = a + b
    adc edx,0        ;c_high = carry
```

..and the multiplication might look like:

```
    mul ebx          ;edx:eax = a * b
```